# Scipy Differential Evolution initial solution(s) input

Tags: python, scipy, initialization, scipy-optimize, differential-evolution

Does anyone know how to feed in an initial solution or matrix of initial solutions into the differential evolution function from the Scipy library?

The documentation doesn't explain if its possible but I know that initial solution implementation is not unusual. Scipy is so widely used I would expect it to have that type of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after review and testing I believe I now understand it.
There are a set of parameters that the `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(...)` function can accept, one is the `init` parameter which allows you to upload an array of solutions. Personally I was looking at a set of coordinates so enumerated them into an array and fed in 99 other variations of it (100 different solutions) and fed this matrix into the `inti` parameter. I believe it needs to have more than 4 solutions or your are going to get a tuple error.

I probably didn't need to ask/answer the question though it may help others that got equally confused.